# Export c# array to csv file with title

Tags: c#, arrays, csv

I tried to export an 2-D array from c# to a csv file but last several rows are missing in the csv file.I don't know where the problem is in my code.

First,I'd like to know if my code is not correct?

Second,is it possible to add a title for each row  in the csv file .

Thanks in advance

Here is an example of my array in c#

```
 string[,] array=new string[]{{2000,2}，{2001,4}}
```

I want to a result like this in csv file with title

```
  Date   C1
  2000   2
  2001   4
```

My code:

```
 var outfile=new.streamwriter(@"fileadress.csv");
 for(int i=0;i<array.GetUpperbound(0);i++)
 {
   string content="";
  for(int j=0;j<array.GetUpperbound(1);j++)
   {
     content+= array[i,j]+";";
   }
  outfile.WriteLine(content);

 }
```

Comment: `StreamWriter`s are `IDisposable`, so you should `Dispose()` them when you've finished...

Comment: also your example is not valid C# as is

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a lot of problems in the code shown. The most important is the wrong usage of `GetUpperBound` that return the 'upperbound' of your array, and your example this upperbound is 1 (not 2) thus the `< array.UpperBound` skips the last position in the array.

I suggest a reworking of your code in this way

```
// This is an array of strings right?
string[,] array=new string[,]{{"2000","2"},{"2001","4"}};

// Use a StringBuilder to accumulate your output
StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder("Date;C1\r\n");
for (int i = 0; i <= array.GetUpperBound(0); i++)
{
    for (int j = 0; j <= array.GetUpperBound(1); j++)
    {
         sb.Append((j==0 ? "" : ";") + array[i, j]);        
    }
    sb.AppendLine();
}

// Write everything with a single command 
File.WriteAllText(@"fileadress.csv", sb.ToString());
```

Comment: File.WriteAllText(@"fileadress.csv", sb.ToString());

Comment: Yes, changed it, could you refresh the answer?

Comment: I tested it in my program. But it says file doesn't exist. I'd like to ask you this question,but then i found out i missed `using System.IO`. my comment is a mistake.